How do you decode Raw Instruction Data using Python?
I want to get Sol reserves and token reserves for a newly create pump.fun token. On Solscan, I can see these values in the inner instructions of the tokens creation signature. Heres an example:
https://solscan.io/tx/aGU881DDvgpeezs9mUFJWv3KYkwEggWEQtcxTCupovLhLfgZ3fpwLWyGmA8bbzaQ4JxW39uA29zxHvx5LSBG3Qu
Under instruction "#6.4 - Pump.Fun: Unknown" you can see "virtualSolReserves" and "virtualTokenReserves" in the Events section. My question is how do I get the value of these fields.
When I use getTransaction(), I can get the "Instruction Data Raw". For example, using the same solscan transaction above I can get the Raw Instruction Data in encoded form, which looks like:
2K7nL28PxCW8ejnyCeuMpbXf8Xj7ysXeidJ55TJtZ8PzmG6NLHutyvhym8DqCYcg92aNSXYc4zw6BTJH2matHQR2vqYABBozk3wQJnArhbuCarwm6a1rdvkWiQS8JzqX5citcf3Hf8VMppEpJHtxDQ7J6FJHdnvUG7tyfqG6iU2wpqKR9MZS8515ZAXq
(on the solscan link provided, you can see this by control-f "e445a52e51cb9a1dbddb7fd34ee661eec5c7cc3d63eb826f29ed1c13ed12b623b18dc813f9f0068ae959561c0ed153ef00a3e111000000002d269589a90900000102d9b0c8ef65efba9ce4f49d239deb27e0b90af8432c7f91726f4f185f2a7a971803656600000000004f050e07000000d3e942be39c6030000a3e11100000000d3513072a8c70200" and then hitting the little wheel next to it to the encoded form)
Ultimately, I am wondering how decode this raw instruction data to get its information and values. How would I create a program in PYTHON to decode this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

You can use the deserialize method from the Transaction class of solana.py to acheive this.
Refer to the documentation here: https://michaelhly.com/solana-py/core/transaction/

I am having the same issue. but I am using js.
You can try deserialize sample transactions as below but I am facing the same issue with more complex transactions.
#1 - Compute Budget: SetComputeUnitLimit --- v1 (with bytes)
const hexToBytes = (hex) => {
  let bytes = [];
  for (let c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2) {
    bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
  }
  return bytes;
};

const decodeInstruction = (hexData) => {
  const bytes = hexToBytes(hexData);
  console.log(bytes.length);

  return {
    discriminator: bytes.slice(0, 1).reduce((acc, byte, index) => acc + (byte << (8 * index)), 0),
    units: bytes.slice(1, 5).reduce((acc, byte, index) => acc + (byte << (8 * index)), 0)
  }
};

const hexData = "0290d00300"; // hex data !!!
const decodedData = decodeInstruction(hexData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(decodedData, null, 2));

#1 - Compute Budget: SetComputeUnitLimit --- v2 (with borsh)
const borsh = require('borsh');
const bs58 = require('bs58');
const schema = { 'struct': { 
  'discriminator': 'u8', 
  'units': 'u32' 
} };
const data = "HnkkG7"; // encoded data !!!

const decoded = borsh.deserialize(schema, Buffer.from(bs58.decode(data)));
console.log(decoded);

#6 - Pump: Buy --- mixed
const borsh = require('borsh');
const bs58 = require('bs58');

const hexToBytes = (hex) => {
  let bytes = [];
  for (let c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2) {
    bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
  }
  return bytes;
};

function encodedToHex(encodedData) {
  // Decode the base58 encoded data into a buffer
  const buffer = Buffer.from(bs58.decode(encodedData));
  
  return buffer.toString('hex');
}

const decodeInstruction = (hexData) => {
  const bytes = hexToBytes(hexData);
  console.log(bytes.length);

  return {   
    amount: bytes.slice(0, 16).reduce((acc, byte, index) => acc + (byte << (8 * index)), 0),
    maxSolCost: bytes.slice(16, 23).reduce((acc, byte, index) => acc + (byte << (8 * index)), 0)
  }
};

const schema = { 'struct': { 'amount': 'u64', 
  'maxSolCost': 'u64' 
} };
const encodeddata = "AJTQ2h9DXrBiiXimcEJkmSTSbrNoMJQs9";

const hexData = encodedToHex(encodeddata);
const decodedData = decodeInstruction(hexData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(decodedData, null, 2));

// RESULTS
// { amount": -2034364355, "maxSolCost": 303000000 } // v1 (with bytes)
// { amount: 16927863322537952870n, maxSolCost: 10623762376237n } // v2 (with borsh)

#6 - Pump: Buy RESULTS
|                | amount                | maxSolCost             |
| -------------- | --------------------- | ---------------------- |
| v1 (bytes)     | -2034364355           | 303000000 - Ok      |
| v2 (borsh)     | 16927863322537952870n | 10623762376237n - Ok (BUT it should be the amount) |
| solscan | 10623762376237 | 303000000       |
I do not know why it the same logic do not work well on instructions #6 and #6.4. Only what I found out that there is a little more bytes than it used to be regarding to the "Input Args"/"Events" data structures. Maybe there is a step what needs to be implemented on those instructions.
With  #6.4. it is even worse as it also includes publicKey types andit is even more complicated.
